# How can I access to the resources of a library for Android?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-library

I am trying to access a library that contains some strings and drawables. In my main project I add the library as a module. The problem is that when I want to reference in a layout to a string or a color resource, I can't.
According to the guide of the API syntax, I use *@[package.of.the.library]:type/resource_name*, but this does not work.

I add an example of the layout that I use for testing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:mylibrary="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.mylibrary.resources"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@mylibrary:string/testing_text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried using `xmlns:mylibrary="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` instead of `xmlns:mylibrary="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.mylibrary.resources"` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `compile project(":mylibrary")` to your app build.gradle file dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":mylibrary")
    ...rest of dependencies for project
}
```

Comment: did u see my answer i suggested the same thing

Comment: @ankitagrawal Yes, it is true, but I marked the answer of Joopkins by the contribution of code. I have also voted your answer, Thanks!

Comment: okk, i didnt know you need code, thanks for explanation and no issue if joopkins answer help you bettter , anyways use my 2nd suggestion for accessing resources and string

Answer (score 2):

First add the module as dependency to main project build.gradle file

```
compile project(":module_name")
```

where **module_name** is name of module project

and then u can access string or color just like normal string and color

```
@string/testing_text
```